# Byte Range File Locking in .NET (4.5, 4.7, 4.7.2, 4.8)

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I am developing a Btree ISAM file class which needs to lock/unlock small ranges of bytes (1 at minimum) and have come across a problem with the byte range locking features (.Lock and .Unlock) of the FileStream class. These FileStream Lock and Unlock methods appear to be working. The problem I have is when I try to read data from another process - the Read operation fails when I try to read part of the file that has not been locked by another process. An example is:

1/ Process A Locks 50 bytes starting at offset 20 in file A.

2/ Process B Reads 8 bytes from offset 0 in file A.

Step 2 is failing with an IO Exception saying part of the requested range is locked by another process.

It appears that the FileStream class allocates a buffer when the file is opened and attempts to fill this buffer with bytes that are outside of the range requested when I use the Read method. I reduced the buffer size to 1 which has alleviated the problem but not solved it. Additionally I see no.NET way to open a file without buffering.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you reduce Program's A and B down to a [mcve] and add that to your question, rather than trying to convey what they do through narrative please?

Comment: On reviewing the FileStream class's code, I believe you should be able to work around this by setting the Position property vs using Seek as long as the buffer size is <= to the number bytes read.  The Position property initializes some fields that are used to load the read buffer.